# mysql simultaneous query for insertion

Tags: mysql, locking, sql-insert

When several users try to insert into the same table at the same time, mysql locks the table while implementing the first query.

Question is:

mysql declines other requests or puts them in queue and after the table is unlocked will implement other requests as well?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will handle the requests one at a time so in a sense will queue them until the lock has been released on the table to allow the next session to perform its request.